# jruby ubuntu 14.04 : not able to install gems

Tags: ubuntu, jruby

I installed jruby on my ubuntu 14.04 :

```
sudo apt-get install jruby
```

I now try to install the Buby gem as follow :

```
sudo jruby -S gem install buby
```

but I get the following error :

```
Error opening script file: /–S (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Your jruby command does not seem to be recognizing the `-S`. Is the `jruby` binary in your path? I googled and found it is in `~/jruby/bin` which is not in your path by default.

Comment: jruby is located: /usr/bin/jruby.rb    /usr/bin/jruby    /usr/lib/jruby    /usr/bin/X11/jruby.rb    /usr/bin/X11/jruby          /usr/share/man/man1/jruby.1.gz

Comment: Ok it is in `/usr/bin`. FYI in the future when you want to find what executable is being used in your path you should do `which executable-name`.